# One ' to much in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to write to an string something like this:

```
arr << "Icd3code.create!({:text => '#{variable1}'})" + "\n"
```

My problem is that variable 1 is an string, that contains an **'** :

```
variable1 = "Ami's house"
```

So that at the end the ouput of my code is this:

```
Icd3code.create!({:text => 'Ami's house'})
```

How you can see now i have one **'** to much! I dont know what i can do to avoid this problem! Thanks

Comment: What you're attempting to do looks really, really unsafe. I hope you aren't trying to execute these :)

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with unsafe? It simply wont work!

Comment: Meaning, if you're intending on building a string along the lines of SomeModel.create and then trying to execute that later on, that could be exploited and would be a security risk. Hence, unsafe.

Comment: You could use `%q{...}` while building your string instead of `'...'` but, like @varatis stated, this is very, very unsafe. I hesitate putting it as the answer because there is a much larger issue here as to why you feel the need to do it this way.

Comment: I thought it is an normal practice to make seeds? Or do you mean something else

Comment: This is not normal practice to make seeds. Maybe you should state what you're trying to do, and then we can answer that.

Comment: Please post it as answer! Thanks

Comment: @user2724695 Make seeds? You are storing executable code as a string! That's the unsafe part.  It doesn't matter what that code does, because someone can make that string store code that does _almost anything_.

Comment: The thing is i have an very large database, that later on should be visible for the users! I dont know how i should it make instead of an seed file? I mean i can delete this seed file later! Or please say me how you would do it!

Comment: I mean the code i showed to you only runs on my computer locally to generate an ssed file, that i can insert into my applikation!

Comment: _You could use %q{...}_ . Wrong.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell what do you say now?

Comment: @7stud Sorry, I meant `%Q{...}`. Slip of the fingers. Though, if the OP is wanting to define `variable1` at a later point, `string = %Q{Icd3code.create!({:text => '%s'})}; variable = "Ami's House"; string % variable1` would work better.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
variable1 = "Ami's house" 
puts %Q[Icd3code.create!({:text => "#{variable1}"})] + "\n"

--output:--
Icd3code.create!({:text => "Ami's house"})
```

Comment: At the end of my code i have: File.open('neu.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write(arr) } So maybe you have to change your code that all lines are written to arr an then saved in neu.txt

Comment: Thanks your the first one how really helped me

Comment: NO NO NO NO NO. What happens if variable1 is set to `"\"}); Icd3code.destroy_all!; "`. Try it

Comment: @user2724695 It can cause a type of [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) that is using Ruby code instead of SQL. Major potential security breach. Especially if you are looking to provide users with database access later on, as you stated.

Comment: @user2724695 woah, that seems a bit unnecessary. I'm just pointing out that this solution gives attackers the ability to run arbitrary ruby code on your server!

Comment: @user2724695, perhaps you can think up a more respectful way to say "huh?!"

Comment: So i only should use ' and not " ?

Comment: As hdgarrmod stated, this is quite simply a terrible idea. Do not do this. If OP stated his problem, there is undoubtedly a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood, you want to loop over some input, building up a list of parameters, which you plan to later use to create some records. If that's the case, I think you're better off using hashes, instead of strings:

```
# Let's pretend this came from the big, bad, world
inputs = ["Ami's house", "Fred's house", "Jim's house"]

creation_params = []

inputs.each do |input|
  creation_params << {:text => input}
end
```

Then you could create all the Icd3codes, like this:

```
creation_params.each do |params|
  Icd3code.create!(params)
end
```

Or you could save them in a text file, for later:

```
File.open('dest', 'w') do |f|
  f.write(creation_params.to_json)
end
```

Comment: No, sorry this wont work, because i have a lot of diffrent variables in different lines! But finally i came to the solution that i will change all ' to `

Comment: This is exactly right.  Keep your raw data as data, and keep that raw data out of your code.